# Italy national reingresso visa, Type D, single, allowed to travel around Schengen area?

Tags: visas, italy

Permit Residence lost, currently holding Italy national reingresso re-entry visa, type D, number of entries 01. The new PR is still in progress.

I wonder that holding of the Italy national reingresso re-entry visa, type D, number of entries 01 is allowed to travel around in Schengen area during its valid time, such as Germany and Finland?

Answer (score 2):

As far as other Schengen countries are concerned, *yes,* any D visa or residence permit issued by another Schengen country authorizes the bearer to travel within the Schengen area, subject to the 90/180 rule, unless there is a specific annotation to the contrary.

I suppose it is possible that *Italian* law imposes a travel restriction, requiring you to stay inside Italy.  Some countries have similar restrictions in various circumstances.  I think this is unlikely, but I do not know the relevant Italian law.  In any event, that question is better suited to [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com), since it's about your relationship with your country of temporary residence.

As far as traveling to other countries in the Schengen area, which *is* on topic here, you have nothing to worry about.